# While using recursive function calls when to use 'return'?

Tags: c, function, recursion

I am confused when to use 'return' while using recursive function calls.

I am trying to find the "GCD (Greatest common divisor)" of two numbers. What I actually thought would work is:

```
  include <stdio.h>
  int gcd (int a, int b);

  int main ()
  {
   int a, b;
   printf ("Enter two numbers \n");
   scanf ("%d %d", &a, &b);
   printf ("GCD for numbers %d and %d is %d\n", a, b, gcd(a,b));
   return (0);
   }

   int gcd (int a, int b)
   {
    while (a!=b)
     {
      if (a > b)
       gcd(a-b,b);
      else if (b > a)
       gcd(a,b-a);
     }
    return (a);
   }
```

But the above code continuously accepts numbers from terminal and fails to run the code.

However, when I replace the function definition as follows the code works as expected returning the right values.

```
   int gcd (int a, int b)
   {
    while (a!=b)
     {
      if (a > b)
       return gcd(a-b,b);
      else if (b > a)
       return gcd(a,b-a);
     }
    return (a);
   }
```

As you see the only change is addition of 'return' before the recursive function call. Why is return required there considering in both the cases I am calling the gcd(arg1, arg2) function?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but think about that loop for a while... When will either `a`or `b` change, making the condition change?

Comment: As for your question, you say that the function should return an `int` value, but what value will you be returning from the function? If you want to return a value from a function, you need an explicit `return` statement.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is return required there considering in both the cases I am calling the gcd(arg1, arg2) function?

For the same reason that it is required any other time you call a function and wish to return the value that was returned by that function call; because calling it only calls it, and does nothing else with the resulting value.

> I am confused when to use 'return' while using recursive function calls.

Use `return` for a recursive call, whenever you would use `return` for any other function call - i.e.: when, and because, that call returns the value you wish to return this time around.

Imagine that we have

```
#include "magic.h" /* defines gcd2(), which computes GCD in some mysterious way */
```

And then instead of making recursive calls, we delegate some of the work to that:

```
/* Of course this solution also works, but is not interesting
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    return gcd2(a, b);
} */

/* So, let's do something that actually shows off the recurrence relation */
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return gcd2(a-b, b);
    else if (b > a)
        return gcd2(a, b-a);
    else
        return a;
}
```

(I also removed the `while` loop, because it is not relevant to the algorithm; of course, a `return` is reached in every circumstance, and this breaks the loop.)

I assume I don't need to go over the mathematical theory; and also I assume it is clear why `return` is needed for the `gcd2` results.

But it *doesn't actually matter* how the work is delegated; if `gcd` is a function that correctly computes GCDs, and `gcd2` is also such, then a call to `gcd2` may be replaced by a call to `gcd`. This is the secret - calling a function recursively is *not actually different* from calling one normally. It's just that considering the possibility, requires a clearer understanding of how calling a function works and what it actually does.

---

Of course, it is also possible to make good use of the original `while` loop - by subtracting out as much as possible *before* doing the recursion. That might look like:

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
        while (a > b)
            a -= b; /* prepare a value for the recursion. */
        return gcd(a, b); /* and then recurse with that value. */
    else if (b > a)
        while (b > a)
            b -= a; /* similarly. */
        return gcd(a, b);
    else /* a == b */
        return a;        
}
```

But then we might as well go all the way and convert to an iterative approach:

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    while (a != b)
        /* whichever is greater, adjust it downward, leaving an (a, b)
           pair that has the same GCD. Eventually we reach an equal pair,
           for which the result is known. */
        if (a > b)
            a -= b;
        else
            b -= a;
    return a; /* since the loop exited, they are equal now. */
}
```

(And we also could do modulo arithmetic to accomplish multiple subtractions at once; this is left as an exercise.)

Comment: This might be a lot longer than it needs to be - it's hard to find the right cutoff point between explaining the problem, and just explaining recursion in general. Also, it has been a very long time since I wrote any C code, so there definitely could be an error somewhere.

Comment: I think you need some braces in this.

Answer (score 0):

The first gcd function "tries" to compute the gcd but in the end always returns `a` unchanged.

The second gcd function computes the gcd recursively and each invocation returns a gcd.

Comment: Technically the first variant will not return at all if `a` is not equal to `b`.

Comment: Let's consider an example; gcd(9,12) -> gcd (9,3) -> gcd (6,3) -> gcd (3,3). I get out of the while loop here (when I reach the function call gcd(3,3)) and then return value of '3'. This should not change even in the first case when I don't use return right?

Comment: @SaideepPavuluri Without the `return` statements you do ***not*** "get out of the loop". What makes you think your loop will end?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what you say is exactly what I am getting when I run the code - infinite loop. Regarding, why I think my loop will end without return - when I call the function gcd(3,3) - see my previous comment example, I don't enter the 'while' loop and the gcd function shall return the value of 'a' that is 3.

Comment: @SaideepPavuluri Like I said before, to return from a function it needs to end. Either by the closing `}` or with an explicit `return` statement. With your example you recurse down to ` gcd (3,3)` which will return (since the condition `a != b` is false and the loop never happens) but then you get back to the `gcd (6,3)` call, where `a != b` will *always* be true, and the loop never ends, and keep on calling `gcd (3,3)` forever.

Comment: @SaideepPavuluri You really need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code (and into function calls), then you could easily see this happen.